# How to add modules from external directories in Python

Tags: python

I know this must be fairly easy but I cannot make it work for my case. I have the following structure:

```
project_root
    __init__.py
    backend
        __init__.py
        application
            __init__.py
            admin
                __init__.py
                models
    scheduling
        __init__.py
        my_script.py
```

I want to load some objects from `__init.py__` file under `application`
as well as some other objects from `models.py` file under `application.admin`.

How to do that `without` using `sys.path` or similar technique?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable PYTHONPATH to the root directory of your project. Python will look for modules there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your entry point.

If I am reading your question correctly, you would like to access objects in `application/__init__.py` from code within admin/models.py?

If your entry point is `__init__.py` in the project_root folder ie.

`user@host:/$python project_root/__init__.py`

Then from within your models.py code you can simply write:

`from backend.application import myobject`